# Generate tables from entity in eclipse doesnt add the auto_increment property to primary key

Tags: mysql, eclipse, hibernate, jpa-2.1

When I try to create tables from entity using "Generate tables from entity", it creates the tables, but does not add the property `auto_increment` to the primary key.

Here is a sample entity:

```
@Entity
public class Post implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -665356579933050521L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long postID;

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name = "postOwnerID", referencedColumnName = "userID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private UserCredential postOwner;

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="postType", referencedColumnName="postType", nullable=false)
private PostTypeEnum postType;

@ManyToOne(optional=true)
@JoinColumn(name="postEvent", referencedColumnName="eventID", nullable=true)
private Event postEvent;

@Column(nullable=false)
@Embedded
private AuditTrail auditTrail;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Message> postMessages;

public Post(){
}

}
```

**UPDATE**
I tried to alter the table post using alter table sql query to which i go the following error:

```
ERROR 1833 (HY000): Cannot change column 'POSTID': used in a foreign key constraint 'FK_POSTRECIPIENT_postID' of table 'class_register.postrecipient'
```

Comment: @AleksandrM I know but still eclipse is not adding auto_increment property to the sql script it is generating

Comment: How did you check that?

Comment: @AleksandrM by using 'show columns from table' command in mysql

Comment: You mean in Extra column? Try to drop your table (or whole db, if you can) and generate it again.

Comment: @AleksandrM I have tried it but same result every time.

Comment: Can you generate sql script for `Post` entity and put it in your question.

Comment: @AleksandrM Here is the query:    CREATE TABLE POST (POSTID BIGINT NOT NULL, CREATEDBY VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, CREATEDTIME DATETIME NOT NULL, ISACTIVE TINYINT(1) default 0 NOT NULL, LASTMODIFIEDBY VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, LASTMODIFIEDTIME DATETIME NOT NULL, postEvent BIGINT, postOwnerID BIGINT, postType VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (POSTID))

Comment: Can you try with `GenerationType.IDENTITY`.